# How to access door switch for a Kenmore Elite Dryer?

Tags: dryer, appliances

I have a Kenmore Elite electric dryer and the door switch appears to have failed.  But I'm not sure how to access the switch.   It appears to be a very similar switch on many models (so the guides I've found aren't model-specific either)

I found a video for a model with the lint screen in the lid.  That one has a couple of screws holding down the lid under the lint screen panel.  But my model (110.66962501) has the lint screen in the door and no other panels (or visible screws) on the lid.

I've tried pulling the lid up.  The lid easily moves up a half inch in front and stops.  It feels like it might be held by some type of friction clip, but even with quite a bit of force, it doesn't release.   I'm not certain if this is correct, so I don't want to get in with shims or bang with a hammer yet.

How to find the right way to open the lid for this model?

Comment: Have you hoisted the lid as far as it will go, then taken a look inside the gap with a flashlight lighting things up for you? You might find that there are spring clips or that it is just a friction fit and pulling harder _is_ the way to go.

Comment: In general, most appliance parts are (evidently) deliberately hard to get to so that you'll call someone else to do it, or throw in the towel and buy a new one instead.  You need to look for resources specific to your model to know how to take your model apart - they are usually available at appliance parts sources. The tricks used to make sure you'll break something if taking it apart without looking for details vary, so it's not really possible to generalize. Diagrams here: https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model/2xuib33rz8-000583/kenmore-elite-11066962501-dryer-parts

Comment: Is this video closer to yours? Doesn't **show** much of the process, sad to say, but mentions "sliding" the top off, not pulling it up.  And three screws in the back under the control panel area that needs the "putty-knife spring clip trick," which is shown. https://youtu.be/QNa6zfzrm5k

Comment: @Ecnerwal, yeah I'm not too impressed with that "video", but I finally understood what it was trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

The "flashlight under the lid" just wasn't helping me because I couldn't understand which part was what.  Without a bit more knowledge, I didn't want to force it.

Ecnerwal re-pointed me at a ["video"](https://youtu.be/QNa6zfzrm5k).  I'd encountered it before, but because it's static images (that I didn't think shows the critical part clearly), I'd not gone back to it.

But there are two clips on the front corners of the control panel where it sits on the lid.  When a scraper is shoved into that spot from front to rear, it will pop it off the panel. The video shows most of this.  Just know that you don't have to "pry" the control panel up.  A flat scraper pushed straight back is sufficient.  Lift up from the side to help remove the  clip.

Underneath are three hex head screws.  When removed, the lid can slide forward.  The bits in the front that I hoped were friction clips are just slide clips.  Once the lid is off, access to the door switch is available.

Comment: Sounds precisely like the kind of gymnastics required to get a DIY mechanic to break things requiring replacement. Glad you sorted it and thanks for posting!